# Google Maps Drop multiple Pins in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, dictionary, sdk

I am working on an application in which I need to show Google Map with user current location and retrieve address.I have implemented that part and it is working, Now I need to find nearest restaurant in that place using google place API. I have integrated them and it is showing me all the nearest restaurant. However I need to drop pins on that Restaurant. I have used GMSMarker for showing single pin, however I need to show multiple pins after getting information. Below is my source code. Please help to drop multiple pins.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    currentLocation = [locationManager location];
    coordinate = [currentLocation coordinate];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude zoom:15];

    GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300) camera:camera];
    mapView.delegate = self;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
    marker.title = @"Current Location";
    marker.snippet = @"Test";
    marker.map = mapView;

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!(error))
         {
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
             NSLog(@"\nCurrent Location Detected\n");
             NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
             NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
             NSString *Address = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:locatedAt];
             NSString *Area = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.locality];
             NSString *Country = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.country];
             NSString *CountryArea = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", Area,Country];
             NSLog(@"%@",CountryArea);
             NSLog(@"%@",Address);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error %@", error);
             NSLog(@"\nCurrent Location Not Detected\n");
             //return;
         }
     }];
}


-(IBAction)nearbyPlaces:(id)sender {

    NSString *str=[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=5000&types=%@&sensor=true&key=%@",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,currentLocation.coordinate.longitude,@"restaurant",@"AIzaSyB0jFNjBtUlr-zbhiCm-xduYR1YkDMV1Fo"];
    NSLog(@"\n\n URL %@",str);
    NSURL *strurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@"%7C"]];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:strurl];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) {

            self.view = mapView_;
            id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
            if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])
            {
                NSLog(@"\n\n.......This is Mutable Array");
            }
            else
            {
                if ([[result objectForKey:@"results"] count] > 0) {

                    NSLog(@">>>>>>>> dict keys :%lu \nFull Address : %@\n LatLong : %@ \n total result : %lu", (unsigned long)[[result objectForKey:@"results"] count],[[result objectForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"vicinity"],[[[result objectForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"geometry"]valueForKey:@"location"],(unsigned long)[[result objectForKey:@"results"]count]);

                    for (int i=0; i<[[result objectForKey:@"results"] count]; i++) {
                        NSLog(@"%@",[[[result objectForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"name"]);
                        NSLog(@"%@",[[[result objectForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"vicinity"]);
                        NSLog(@"%@",[[[result objectForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"reference"]);

                        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
                        location.latitude = [[[[[[result objectForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"geometry"]valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"lat"]doubleValue];
                        location.longitude = [[[[[[result objectForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"geometry"]valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<[youArray count]; i++)
        {            
            CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);
            GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
            marker.title = @"Title";
            marker.snippet = @"Subtitle";
            marker.flat=YES;
            marker.map = _mapView_results;
        }
```

Here is the code which I used to do the same.

Comment: Well as soon as I add this code, this shows me a black screen. Please let me know about this.

Comment: Take out a separate array having lat,long and other related information and then loop through that array and call it at appropriate place where you want to show.